# How to import/Inject scss file programmably with Nuxt?

Tags: webpack, sass, nuxt.js, webpack-style-loader

As the question, I like to load different theme by name variable, but i always got empty object from `themeLoader`.

I have found a lot paper but no answer. hope someone can help me.

```
function themeLoader (name) {
  return import(`../assets/themes/${name}.scss`)
}
export default {
  ...
  async fetch () {
    const name = 'test'
    console.log(themeLoader(name))
    const style = document.createElement('style')
    style.content = cssString
    // append to head
  }
  ...
}
```

---

### Update

I move import to nuxt head function, but i want to know am i doing right?

```
head () {
    const name = 'test'
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "themes/[request]" */'../assets/themes/' + name + '/index.scss')
    return {
      title: this.docTitle
    }
  }
```

Comment: By design a SCSS file is compiled to CSS on build step. So you cannot compile it on runtime. But try the following lib to compile on browser side: https://github.com/medialize/sass.js

Comment: @NicolasPennec thansk for reply. the paper https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import say it will try to resolve all possible file determine by path. i have tried in nuxt head function,and it's work fine. it's weird i know, so i want to know the right way